# Getting "invalid syntax" error while reading data from text file using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, syntax-error, datareader

I'm trying to read text file using pyspark. Data in file is comma separated.

I've already tried reading data using sqlcontext.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context

filePath = './data_files/data.txt'

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

print(fileData)
schema = StructType([StructField('ID', IntegerType(), False),
                     StructField('Name', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('Project', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('Location', StringType(), False)])
print(schema)

fileRdd = sc.textFile(fileData).map(_.split(",")).map{x => org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x:_*)}
sqlDf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(fileRdd,schema)
sqlDf.show()
```

I'm getting following error.

> File "", line 1
>       fileRdd = sc.textFile(fileData).map(*.split(",")).map{x => org.apache.spark.sql.Row(x:**)}
>                                                            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Well, is it Python? You can't use Scala syntax in Python.

Comment: can you please suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: Check the examples: https://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Answer (score 2):

I've tried using following code and it is working fine.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
sc = SparkContext("local", "first app")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

filePath = "./data_files/data.txt"

# Load a text file and convert each line to a Row.
lines = sc.textFile(filePath)
parts = lines.map(lambda l: l.split(","))
# Each line is converted to a tuple.
people = parts.map(lambda p: (p[0].strip(), p[1], p[2], p[3]))

# The schema is encoded in a string.
schemaString = "ID Name Project Location"

fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in schemaString.split()]
schema = StructType(fields)

schemaPeople = sqlContext.createDataFrame(people, schema)
schemaPeople.show()
```